# Android UI and layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple problem but could not solve it with clean solution .
Suppose there are two textviews horizontally next to each other. I want to make them such that 
second textview come just right to first and first should grow as much as it can without putting second textview out of screen (means second textview should always be visible).

Comment: Place both in `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`. Make one use `android:layout-width="wrap_content"` and the other `android:layout-width="fill_parent"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:you could always use Relative layout and try scaling them in the Graphical layout.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be, putting the two textViews in a LinearLayout and assign each textView a weight attribute. The LinearLayout divides the space between those views accordingly to the weight. For example if the first textview has weight 3 and the second has weight 2, the width for the first textview would be 3/5 superviews width and the second would be 2/5.

Another solution would be to put the second textView with a fixed width aligned right to the parent RelativeLayout, and the first view to be leftof the second view with the width 'match_parent'

Comment: I want second textview to appear just after first (so to user it should look like a single text) so assigning weight will not work I think and also If I assign fixed width and make it right allign (second textview can also of variable length) then again there can be a gap between first and second view

Comment: Assigning weight will make the two textViews fill the parent's width, they will be right after eachother

Comment: After assigning weight I can see there is gap between textviews